# draw and fill options ignored in column style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

The `draw` and `fill` options are ignored when supplied to `column 1/.style` in a tikz matrix, but `text` color and other options aren't:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, column 1/.style={draw=red, fill=blue, text=green}] {
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Matrix containing A B C D with A and C green, but no border and no fill]

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `column 1` style is not applied to the node in the entries in column 1 but to the cell.  With a standard matrix (ie not one with `matrix of nodes`) then the cell can contain things other than nodes so the style has to be more general.  So you should consider the cells as scopes, not paths.  And to affect the nodes within a scope you need to use the `every node/.style={...}` key.  That is, if you want to use a scope to affect a node you write:

```
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw=blue}]
\node {This will have a blue outline};
\end{scope}
```

So you need to do the same with the matrix.  Thus `column 1/.style={every node/.style={draw = red, fill = blue, text = green}}` is correct.  It might seem a little clunky, but it's there because of the greater flexibility in cell contents.

If there isn't already (and without looking in the manual I don't know) then you could define a style `column 1 nodes` which did the double for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133636/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, column 1/.style={every node/.style={draw=red, fill=blue, text=green}}] {
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{column 1 nodes/.style={column 1/.style={every node/.style={#1}}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, column 1 nodes={draw=red, fill=blue, text=green}] {
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know how one would define a "family" of options based on the template `column #1 nodes=#2`, in a more elegant way than using a foreach loop to define many options? I tried `column/.style args={#1:#2}{column #1/.style={every node/.style={#2}}}`, which is used like this: `\matrix[matrix of nodes, column=1:{draw=red}, column=2:{draw=blue}] { ... };`, but the syntax doesn't feel quite as idiomatic as it should.

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  TikZ doesn't actually define the `column <n>` styles, it just tries to execute them, and because it executes them when it knows the column number then it just has to do `column \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn/.try`.  You could try emulating that, but my initial experiments draw blank.

Comment: I’d avoid `every node/.style` here and rather use `every node/.append style` to not overwrite the `name=<matrix>-<row>-<column>` setting of `matrix of nodes` (different in CVS). @GeorgesDupéron Take a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124804/16595) and its `rows` style definition where one can apply the same style to multiple  rows (same for columns) via the help of an auxiliary style and the `.list` handler.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Fair point.

Answer (score 4):

You have to explicitly assign the attributes to the nodes of the matrix. Try something like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, column 1/.style={nodes={draw=red, fill=blue, text=green}}] {
      A & B \\
      C & D \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I accepted Andrew Stacey's answer because it condained more explanations, but this one works too (and that's the one I ended up using). Do you know if there's a difference between `nodes=` and `every node/.style=` in that situation (AFAICT both have the same effect)?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron `nodes` is defined `nodes/.style={every node/.append style={#1}}`, it appends keys to the `every node` style while `every node/.style` redefines it.