# How to have table blanks as zeros?

Tags: tables

I would like to know if it is possible to let LaTeX Table intepret `&&` as `&0&`. 
So the blank is not the literal NA or any corresponding here.
Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
AHB        && \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I change the table row to

```
AHB       1 && 1 \\ \hline
```

I would like it be interpreted

```
AHB       1 &0& 1 \\ \hline
```

Comment: Depending on how this table data is generated, I might consider just using an editor's search and replace function to replace all `&&` with `&0&`.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I am thinking something automated solution here.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134209/how-do-i-draw-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-for-a-tikz-matrix/134212#134212

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [collect the cell contents](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) and [test whether it is blank](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collcell}
\newcommand{\emptytozero}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    0%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c | >{\collectcell\emptytozero}c<{\endcollectcell} }
   &   \\
   & 1 \\
 1 &   \\
 1 & 1
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If multiple columns are to be examined, one can define a new column type ([`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) loads [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array).) `\newcolumntype`:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\collectcell\emptytozero}c<{\endcollectcell} }
```

Comment: Can you please say if this method can also be used a shorthand form like `\begin{tabular}{| p | C |}` where `C` is about your `\newcolumntype`?

Comment: @Masi: Yes it can. That's what I suggest at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a very simple version that fills in blank tabular cells with a zero. The check is performed by a new column format `z` which should be used for all columns that have to be filled with zeros if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{z}{>{\zeroIfEmpty}l<{\endzero}}
\def\zeroIfEmpty#1\endzero{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd0=0pt 0\else#1\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| z | z | z | l }
   &   &   &\\
   &   & 1 &\\
   & 1 &   &\\
 1 &   &   &\\
 1 & 1 & 1 &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this is a very simple check which is likely to break in several more complicated situations, e.g., it does break if used in the last column of a tabular (which can be fixed by an extra empty column as shown in the example). So it's probably better to not use it at all. ;-)

Comment: How does your approach differ from Werner's one? Your `newcolumntype` sentence is little longer here.

Comment: @Masi My version simply wraps the zero-or-not-zero check around the standard column format. This has the downside that I can't check for an empty cell directly because the standard formats silently add some commands to cancel extra space at the beginning and end of each cell (note the use of a temporary `\hbox` to circumvent the effects of these commands). OTOH, Werner's version uses the `collcell` package that seems to take more care to remove these extra commands. And it also works when used in the last column of a tabular, which makes his solution the better one, in my eyes.