# Array Alignment using TikZ Matrices; cell over a complete row

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, matrices

I want to align subplots in a pgfplot.

with `\matrix` it is easy to align pictures. My problem is, that I need several rows with two columns/pictures and a last row with a picture over both columns.

Here the not working code illustrating what I wanted to do

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix{
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
        &
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        \begin{axis}[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
        \\  
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

that's the unwanted result

[image]

and that's how I wanted it to look

[image]

I had a look at

- Manual for Package pgfplots by Christian Feuersaenger
- TikZ & PGF Manual by Till Tantau

but did not found a solution (maybe there is non)

Does anybody has a solution for doing it with /matrix (highly appreciated) or maybe another solution?

kind regards
Benjamin

Comment: You may want to have a look to this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21167/31058

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\hspaces` may need to be tweaked, but alignment issues are compounded by the fact that horizontal-axis labels (in some but not all cases) protrude beyond the bounding box of the graphs, and also because not all vertical -axis labels are same width (because of negatives).  The underlying `\stackon` method is, by default, center aligned.  If you think making it left-aligned might make things easier, `\def\stackalignment{l}` before you begin will accomplish it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
\stackon[5pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{5.5ex}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1ex}%
}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]