# tikz: NewDocumentCommand fails to add |[mystyle]| in tikzcd/matrix of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

How could I design a macro (if possible using `\NewDocumentCommand`) to add in a tikz matrix (created via tikzcd) something like `|[stylename]| content`? For now I can do:

```
\newcommand\zxZ[1]{|[Z]| #1}
```

but with NewDocumentCommand, this fails:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\zxZ}{m}{|[Z]| #1}
```

Here is what I get for now:

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{Z}=[fill=green]

% Works
%\newcommand\zxZ[1]{|[Z]| #1}
% Works (but I'd prefer the above |[Z]| since it seems to handle \arr and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21167/116348 better)
%\newcommand\zxZ[1]{\node[Z]{#1};}
% Fails
%\NewDocumentCommand{\zxZ}{m}{\node[Z]{#1};}
% Fails
%\NewDocumentCommand{\zxZ}{m}{|[Z]| #1}

\begin{tikzcd}
  \node[Z]{\alpha}; & \zxZ{\beta}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider replacing the use of `\tikzset` with `\tikzstyle` as per the author of the package: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Comment: @PeterGrill yeah, it's just that tikzstyle format is produced automatically by tikit (a graphical tool to deal with nodes), so I just used it. But thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why `\NewDocumentCommand` is deemed necessary. Anyway, you need to use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`, because of the inner workings of `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
%\usepackage{xparse} % only for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  Z/.style={fill=green},
}

% Works
%\newcommand\zxZ[1]{|[Z]| #1}
% Works (but I'd prefer the above |[Z]|
%\newcommand\zxZ[1]{\node[Z]{#1};}
% Works
%\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\zxZ}{m}{\node[Z]{#1};}
% Works
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\zxZ}{m}{|[Z]| #1}

\begin{tikzcd}
  \node[Z]{\alpha}; & \zxZ{\beta}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for several years.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! Concerning `\tikzstyle`, it's just that `tikzit` produces style files with that syntax, but thanks for mentionning.

Comment: Concerning `\NewDocumentCommand`, it's just that I like the way I can specify arguments a lot better (I mean compared to `\def` and `\newcommand`, I don't care to use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`). And I guess it's consider more solid compared to `\newcommand` no?

Comment: @tobiasBora The usual problem: packing many optional arguments is not a recommended way to define interfaces.

Comment: I've two remarks/questions: first, I tried your method but adding this time some conditions and/or macros... and now it fails again. Any idea what I did wrong? (see my edit) Secondly, I agree with your remark (well especially in LaTeX since you can't define second optional argument without defining the first one), even if I like adding one or two optional arguments. That said, interfaces like pgfkeys are extremely useful, and I like to use the optional argument together with pgfkeys.